# Assign values to DF rows based on string portions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 1 column (these are headernames for another dataframe. I am trying to assign weightings to these based on strings names contained in the rows. They all have long names (classes and subclasses like) seperated by underscores, for example:
email_Trading Only,
readership_unique_client,
roadshow_NDR_Con_Call_Meetings,
forum_meeting,

I would like to assign weights to these based on string instances that occur before/inbetween/after underscores.

Was thinking about creating a dictionary of sorts, but not sure how to loop and iterate through all the rows properly. Pseudocode here:

```
for i in rows: 
     if i contains 'email' #before first underscore
          then 0.5 #assigned to corresponding row in new column of DF
```

Sample Data and output (based on first string portion before underscore(:

```
                                TITLES   WEIGHTS     
2                        emp_full_name     0
3                      emp_office_code     0
4              emp_country_office_code     0
..                                 ...
171   forum_presentation_Platinum Plus     0.5
172  forum_presentation_Private Client     0.5
173          forum_presentation_Silver     0.5
```

Comment: Can you show the sample data and expected output

Comment: have edited in as asked. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the user guide on [how to test for string that contains a pattern](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern).

You can solve it with something like

```
df['WEIGHTS'] = df.TITLES.str.contains('email') * 0.5
```

Or create the column and then update it

```
df['WEIGHTS'] = 0
df.loc[df.TITLES.str.contains('email'), 'WEIGHTS'] = 0.5
```

---

*Update*

`.str` accessors work with regex by default so you can include optional patterns like

```
df.loc[df.TITLES.str.contains('(email)|(forum)'), 'WEIGHTS'] = 0.5
```

You can also get the first part of the strings with

```
label = df.TITLES.str.split().str[0]
```

Then use a mapper with `series.replace`, but you would need to include all possible suffixes

```
df['WEIGHTS'] = label.replace({'email': 0.5, 'forum': 0.2 ...})
```

Comment: works well enough, thank you. trying to add in an or statement here but seems to stop at the first instance. any idea how to fix that?